# {% requireLogin %} not working on extended (layout template) files?

Tags: templating, requirelogin

Is there a reason `{% requireLogin %}` is not firing when using in a parent include?

if I place `{% requireLogin %}` inside the main template file and then use this like so:

homework.twig
`{% extends "_layouts/members-page-layout.twig" %}`

It is not firing? But if I put it inside the homework.twig file directly it fires....
Was hoping t avoid having to add it to multiple templates and just add it to a 'members' parent layout template.

**EDIT 18 July 2020**
Editing the post to include more information
Here is the parent template I am trying to include the `{% requireLogin %}` that is not firing.

```
{# -- Layout template for HTML pages -- #}
{% extends "_boilerplate/_layouts/base-html-layout.twig" %}

{# -- Any <meta> tags that should be included in the <head> #}
{% block headMeta %}
{% endblock headMeta %}

{# -- Any <link> tags that should be included in the <head> #}
{% block headLinks %}
{% endblock headLinks %}

{# -- Any CSS that should be included before </head> -- #}
{% block headCss %}
  {# Google fonts #}
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
  {% include "_inline-css/site-fonts.css" %}
{% endblock headCss %}

{% requireLogin %}

{# -- Page body -- #}
{% block bodyHtml %}
  {% set primarySectionColor      = 'navy' %}
  {% set secondarySectionColor    = 'pink' %}
  
  {% if currentUser.admin %}
    {#    TODO: Make this hide#}
    <div class="max-w-2xl fixed bottom-0 left-0 border border-green-400 m-2">
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="bg-green-100 p-3 text-green-500 text-sm flex">
          {{ svg('@icons/bx/bx-info-circle.svg', class="w-5 h-5 flex-shrink-0 fill-current mr-1") }}
          You are currently logged in as an admin role so you have unrestricted access and therefore you will not see the filtering of content and homework like a member user
          (parent) would see.
        </div>
        <button class="bg-green-500 text-white p-2">
          {{ svg('@icons/bx/bx-info-circle.svg', class="w-8 h-8 flex-shrink-0 fill-current") }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  
  <div id="page-container">
    {# -- Info header, including _navbar.twig -- #}
    {% include "_globals/header.twig" %}
    
    {# - IE notice for Old browsers - #}
    {% include '_globals/ie-notice.twig' %}
    
    <main>
      {# -- Primary content block -- #}
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </main>
    
    {# -- Content that appears below the primary content block -- #}
    {% block subcontent %}
    {% endblock %}
    
    {# -- Info footer -- #}
    {% include "_globals/footer.twig" %}
  
  </div>
{% endblock bodyHtml %}
```

Comment: Sorry this is not going to be very helpful for you, but I can say: It Works OK For Me. Do you maybe have some kind of caching going on?

Comment: No caching as local development at this stage. 
I will have another look then, at least you've confirmed it _should_ work ok.
Thanks.

Comment: What's in your main template file?

Comment: I have added more information to the original question. @RitterKnight

Comment: @TerryUpton: if you move the ``{% requireLogin %}`` tag before ``{% extends %}`` does it work?

Comment: @RitterKnight nope it's the same even if before the `{% extends %}`

Comment: What's inside ``base-html-layout.twig``? Sounds like you may have too many extends going on? You could end up in a situation where you think a tag is going to fire but it's never going to because something else is actually extending it.  That sounds like what could be happening. I would also make sure you're actually not logged in while testing.

Answer (score 1):

Try inside this in the main template file:

```
{% block access %}  
    {% requireLogin %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I am afraid this didn't work either @pavelpavlovich